# Prevent macos automator Terminal ssh script from opening two windows

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, automator, dock

I use a small macOS Automator script to ssh into a remote host so I can add it to the Dock:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script ("ssh robot@example.com;")
end tell
```

When used the first time, I get the expected remote Terminal window, but also an extra local Terminal window.  All subsequent uses only generate a single window to the remote host.

I've tried some small alternatives like:

```
set currentWindow to do script...
```

and:

```
set currentTab to do script...
```

with the same result.  Is there any way to prevent the initial local Terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

I found [a post that has the answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224925/script-opens-two-terminal-windows):

```
tell application "Terminal"
    if not application "Terminal" is running then launch
    do script ("ssh robot@example.com;")
    activate
end tell
```